# pgloader: Unable move data from MYSQL to postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql, pgloader

I installed pgloader using the following command on Ubuntu.

```
$ apt-get install pgloader
```

When I try to move a sample db from mysql to postgrs with the following commands

```
createdb pagila
pgloader mysql://mysqlusr:password@localhost/sampledb postgresql:///pagila
```

I am getting the following error

```
**Error: 'mysql://mysqlusr:password@127.0.0.1:3306/sampledb' does not exists as a section nor as a file**
```

sampledb database exists in mysql and I can login to it using the credentials user: mysqlusr and password: password.

Answer (score 0):

You need a recent enough pgloader to be able to use that command line syntax, and it looks like you're using an old release. Which version of pgloader do you have?